# ActionScript 3.0 HitTestObject on an Array

Tags: actionscript-3

Good afternoon everyone!

I have a small problem in ActionScript 3.0 with hitTestObject.
I would like to chechk if my character hits a platform (I'm making a simple platform game.).
I have a platform object exproted for action script , and i add childs frim this to an array.
Until this point everything goes well, i can put them on stage etc.

I have written a cycle to chechk if my caharacter hits the platform but it doesn't works correctly. My character falls throught the first platforms and only stop's falling when it hits the last platform. (So for the last in the array it works well.)

And now here is this part from my code, i hope someone can help me with it. :)

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;

stop();
var vy:Number=0;
var gv:Number=1;
var sebesseg:Number=4;
var jumped:Boolean=false;
var stay:Boolean=false;

var level:Array=new Array  ;

var gravity:Number=2;

var velocity:Number=1.1;

var platform0:MovieClip=new platform  ;
level.push(addChild(platform0));
level[0].x=200;
level[0].y=450;
var platform1:MovieClip=new platform  ;
level.push(addChild(platform1));
level[1].x=700;
level[1].y=650;
var platform2:MovieClip=new platform  ;
level.push(addChild(platform2));
level[2].x=1000;
level[2].y=800;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, cameraFollowCharacter);

function cameraFollowCharacter(evt:Event) {
root.scrollRect=new Rectangle(PORK1_mc.x-(stage.stageWidth/2)+320,PORK1_mc.y-(stage.stageHeight/2)-50,stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight);
}




stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,gomb);
function gomb(k:KeyboardEvent):void {
    trace(k);
    if (k.keyCode==37) {
        if (sebesseg==2) {
            sebesseg=sebesseg+0;
         } else {
            sebesseg-=1;
         }
    } else if (k.keyCode==39) {
        sebesseg+=1;
    } else if (k.keyCode==Keyboard.ESCAPE) {
        stop();
        root.scrollRect=new Rectangle    (stage.x,stage.y,stage.stageWidth,stage.stageHeight);

        gotoAndStop(2);

    } else if (k.keyCode==Keyboard.F1 && stay==false) {
        stage.frameRate=0;
        stay=true;
    } else if (k.keyCode==Keyboard.F1 && stay==true) {
        stage.frameRate=24;
        stay=false;
    }

   }


stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, megy);
function megy(e:Event):void {
   PORK1_mc.x+=sebesseg;

   gravity*=velocity;
   PORK1_mc.y+=gravity;
   //trace(velocity);

}
```

THIS PART IS THE PROBLEM, HITTESOBJECT ONLY WORKS FOR THE LAST PLATFORM

PORK1_mc.hitPork_mc this is my character (hitPork_mc is an invisible rectangle for better HitTestObject. So as i wrote my char. falls throught the platfroms until the last one, he falls on tha last and stops falling, so for the last platform in the array it works perfectly.
I wouldn't like to change a lot on my code, only on the hitTest part if its possible.

```
 this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleEnterFrame);

 function handleEnterFrame(e:Event):void {
     for (var i:int = 0; i < level.length; i++) {



        if (level[i].hitTestObject(PORK1_mc.hitPork_mc)) {
            velocity=0;

        } else {

            velocity=1.1;
            gravity=4;
        }


     }
  }
```

Thanks for every help in advance!

Comment: Hi everyone!

I solved this problem tonight. I have put the word: return in the if under velocity=0; and it works perfectly, but i still don't understand why does it works now.

Answer (score 0):

With your original code, you do the following for each platform:

- If there is a collision, set velocity to zero.
- If not, set velocity to 1.1.

Since you do this in order, here's what happens when you collide with platform 1 but not 2 or 3:

1. The collision with 1 sets your velocity to zero.
2. The collision with 2 sets your velocity to 1.1.
3. The collision with 3 sets your velocity to 1.1.

Since these happen all in a row in the same frame, the end result is that your character never stops unless the collision is with platform 3.

By returning after setting velocity to zero, you are breaking out of the loop, preventing your collision work from being undone. What you are doing will work, but you can also do it another way which is less concise but may make more sense:

```
function handleEnterFrame(e:Event):void 
{
  var collided:Boolean = false; //This will record if you collided or not.

  for (var i:int = 0; i < level.length; i++) 
  {
    if (level[i].hitTestObject(PORK1_mc.hitPork_mc)) 
    {
      collided = true;
    } 
  }

  if(collided) velocity = 0;
  else
  {
    velocity=1.1;
    gravity=4;
  }
}
```

Note that here we're not applying velocity and gravity inside the for loop because we don't want it to happen for each object we might collide with. Instead, we set it once, after we've determined if we collide with any objects.

This also helps show that you are setting gravity every frame you don't collide even though there doesn't seem to be any point at which you set it to zero; I suspect this is something you want to fix.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now i understand what was the problem and why could i use the return keyword.